# How to remove an element from an Array<String> in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to remove an element from an Array like so:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        gView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_new_load_amount, container, false)

       
        loadAmountString = SharedForSettings.getInstance(context!!).loadAmounts
        loadAmounts =  loadAmountString!!.split(",").toTypedArray()

        return gView
    }

private fun removeValue(value: String) {
        for (i in 0 until loadAmounts!!.size) {
            if (loadAmounts!![i].equals(value)) {
                loadAmounts!!.drop(i)
            }
        }
        loadAmounts!![0]
    }
```

but this code doesn't work. How can I correct this?

Comment: Where is `loadAmounts` defined?

Comment: @Edric Please see my Edit Sir

Comment: It's usually preferable to work with Lists and MutableLists rather than Array. `MutableList` has a `removeValue` function already so you don't have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work is because `drop` removes the first `n` elements. So if you do `drop(5)`, the result is an array without the first 5 elements. The last line in the method is just a normal `get` so it doesn't really remove anything.

Unfortunately, arrays in kotlin don't have a `remove` method. There are many possibilities to solve this.

One that comes to mind after reading your code is to not call `toTypedArray()`. The method `split` already returns a `List<String>` which has the method `remove` that can be called with the element you want to remove.

If you really want to keep it as an array, then you need to implement the remove method yourself. Something like for example:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> Array<T>.removeValue(value: T) =
    filterNot { it == value }.toTypedArray()
```

This will go through the array and remove all elements that match the value passed in. You can use it like `loadAmounts.removeValue("two")`, which would remove all instances of the value `"two"`. Works for other typed arrays too.

Again, there are many ways to do this. I just wanted to highlight that you can also switch to a `List<String`.

Comment: Just my opinion, the name of the function should not be "remove", because that implies that it is editing the collection in place. That's what it means for MutableList. Maybe something like `toArrayWithout`.